# Float element inside div

Tags: css

I want to make a DIV that holds product information. In the DIV, the product description needs to wrap around the product image. I am using align="left" for the image.

My problem is when there is only 1 line of product description, the DIV's height is only 1 line, leaving the image expanding downwards outside of the DIV border in Firefox 1.5. (IE expands the DIV to include the images)

a

Comment: add `overflow: hidden;` to the container

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to your div

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to clear the contents of you DIV. An additional DIV element with clear:both, just inside the end of the container would do it. Or you can use a CSS clearfix http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code, it's hard to tell, but it sounds like you should be using `float:left` rather than `align:left` for the style of the image. Also, the `div` element should ordinarily expand to fit a contained the image, so I imagine there's some extra styling there to look at.